# Chain API calls with React hook useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I need a solution for the following sequence:

The browser checks user's Geolocation (assuming he allows that) -> Longitude and Latitude are kept in state and used for 2 API calls -> Google Reverse Geolocation API checks for city name AND at the same time DarkSky API checks for the weather -> third API waits for results from previous calls and uses it as the query for the third, Unsplash API

Here's my code:

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState({ latitude: '50.049683', longitude: '19.944544' });
const [info, setInfo] = useState({ city: null, weather: null });
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const [cityInfo, weatherInfo] = await Promise.all([
          axios.get(
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&language=en&result_type=locality&key=${GEO_ACC_KEY}`,
          ),
          axios.get(
         `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${WEATHER_ACC_KEY}/${position.latitude},${position.longitude}?exclude=hourly,daily,alerts,flags`,
          ),
        ]);
        setInfo({
          city: cityInfo.data.results[0].address_components[0].short_name,
          weather: weatherInfo.data.currently.summary.toLowerCase(),
        });

        console.log('Info', info); // Results in {city: null, weather: 'null'}

        const photosData = await axios.get(
          `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${info.weather}+${info.city}&page=1&per_page=8&client_id=${UNSPLASH_ACC_KEY}`,
        );

        setPhotos(photosData.data.results);

        console.log('Photos data from API call:', photosData); //Object based on query: "null+null"
        console.log('Photos:', photos); // Empty array
      } catch (err) {
        // Handling errors
      }
    };
    fetchInfo();
  }, []);

  console.log('Info outside axios get', info); // Results in object with city name and current weather
  console.log('photos outside axios get', photos); // Proper result I am looking for
```

Right now the proper data is available ONLY outside useEffect. It does not provide the data for the third API call (right now Unsplash API call uses "null+null" as a query).

So I headed over to useEffect documentation and it says that a second parameter (an array) takes dependencies and updates when any of the state dependencies change.

I tried using it as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInfo = async () => {
      //rest of the code
},
fetchInfo();
}, [info]);
```

It uses proper keywords for the API call (city and weather, instead of null null) BUT creates an infinite API calls.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are not immediate and will reflect in the next render cycle.

Please check this post for more details on this: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332)

Also you must note that you want to chain API call and not call the entire useEffect again on info change. Adding `info` as a dependency will definitely lead to an infinite loop since `info` is being set inside the useEffect.

To solve your problem, You can instead use the value you set to state while making the api call

```
    const newInfo = {
      city: cityInfo.data.results[0].address_components[0].short_name,
      weather: weatherInfo.data.currently.summary.toLowerCase(),
    }

     setInfo(newInfo);

    console.log('Info', info); // Results in {city: null, weather: 'null'}

    const photosData = await axios.get(
      `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${newInfo.weather}+${newInfo.city}&page=1&per_page=8&client_id=${UNSPLASH_ACC_KEY}`,
    );
```